# How to use Spark-Phoenix connection to run join queries on multiple tables?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I want to connect to apache phoenix from spark and run a join sql query. As suggested by Phoenix official website, they have given an example on how to connect to phoenix from spark but it takes single phoenix table name in the configuration. See the example below:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("zkUrl", ZOOKEEPER_URL);
map.put("table", "TABLE_1");
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.sqlContext().load("org.apache.phoenix.spark", map);
df.registerTempTable("TABLE_1");
Dataset<Row> selectResult = df.sparkSession().sql(" SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'ABC' ");
```

In my phoenix-hbase database I have two tables `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2` and I want to run a single sql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 as A JOIN TABLE_2 as B ON A.COLUMN_1 = B.COLUMN_2 WHERE B.COLUMN_2 = 'XYZ';
```

How I can run this query using Phoenix-Spark connection?

Comment: What about loading the two datasets separatly and use `registerTempTable` twice before running the sql query?

Comment: Hi @Shaido, I tried as you suggested and it worked.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above by @Shaido in the comment section I tried and it is working. I am loading the two datasets separately and then registering them as temp table and now I am able to run the join query using those two tables. Below is the sample code.

```
String table1 = "TABLE_1";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("zkUrl", ZOOKEEPER_URL);
map.put("table", table1);
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.sqlContext().load("org.apache.phoenix.spark", map);
df.registerTempTable(tableName);


String table2 = "TABLE_2";
map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("zkUrl", ZOOKEEPER_URL);
map.put("table", table2);
Dataset<Row> df2 = sparkSession.sqlContext().load("org.apache.phoenix.spark", map);
df2.registerTempTable(table2);

Dataset<Row> selectResult = df.sparkSession().sql(" SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 as A JOIN TABLE_2 as B ON A.COLUMN_1 = B.COLUMN_2 WHERE B.COLUMN_2 = 'XYZ' ");
```